# Memory Leaks in Instance method objective 

Tags: iphone

i had a problem with leak. In this editingSessionArray
in this line below:

```
NSMutableArray *sessionsArray = [[NSMutableArray  alloc] initWithArray:[BBWorkoutSession fetchSessionDetail1:selectedWorkoutId]];
```

say that Method returns a objective-c object with a +1 retain count (owing reference):

were did i made the mistake.

Please help me

```
-(void)editingSessionsArray
{
    [[BBAppController sharedInstance] updateLogWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"BEGIN : %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__]];
    if(selectedWorkoutId) { 
    //  NSLog(@"the section id is : %@",selectedWorkoutId);
    NSMutableArray *sessionsArray = [[NSMutableArray  alloc] initWithArray:[BBWorkoutSession fetchSessionDetail1:selectedWorkoutId]];

    /* condition for checking the selected workout id is existing or not */

    if ([workOutSessionData count]) {
        for (int i= 0; i< [workOutSessionData count] ; i++) {
            if ([[[workOutSessionData objectAtIndex:i] allKeys] containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",selectedWorkoutId]]) {
                [workOutSessionData removeObjectAtIndex:i]; 

                return;
            }
        }
    }

    /* If console comes here the workout id is not existed in the main array */


    [mainDict  setValue:sessionsArray forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",selectedWorkoutId]];

    NSMutableDictionary *workoutsList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:sessionsArray,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",selectedWorkoutId],nil] ;
    [workOutSessionData addObject:workoutsList];
    [workoutsList release];
    [sessionsArray release];
    }
    [[BBAppController sharedInstance] updateLogWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"END : %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__]];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If your code goes here:

```
if ([workOutSessionData count]) {
for (int i= 0; i< [workOutSessionData count] ; i++) {
    if ([[[workOutSessionData objectAtIndex:i] allKeys] containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",selectedWorkoutId]]) {
        [workOutSessionData removeObjectAtIndex:i]; 

        return;
    }
}
```

}

you return without releasing workoutList and sessionArray.
You should allocate your sessionArray with an autorelease

```
NSMutableArray *sessionsArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[BBWorkoutSession fetchSessionDetail1:selectedWorkoutId]] autorelease];
```

Comment: +1 for a good eye. Looked at it for 2 mins and didn't see that.